# Why is my nested 'OR' meta_query not working?

Tags: wp-query

I have the following code which I think should work but obviously i'm missing something. Anyone who can tell why this is not correct?

//EDIT
Here is what needs to happen. 'Merk', 'Type' and 'Dummy' are custom fields which are attributes for the product (not woocommerce).

I want to find all products that match either the 'Dummy' attribute false AND 'Merk' and 'Type' match the user input.

-- OR where 'Dummy' is true (AND another field 'Weight' will be matched, but firstly this should work also).

The new WP_Query returns NULL at the moment.

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array( //THIS HAS 9 RESULTS
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'dummy',
            'value' => [false, null],
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'merk',
            'value' => $machine['machine_merk'][0],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'merk_type',
            'value' => $machine['machine_type'][0],
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
    array( //OR THIS HAS 30 RESULTS
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'dummy',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        //and something else
    )
);
```

If I comment one of these 2 arrays to check, they both have results.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of minor formatting changes: an extra nested array that can be deleted, and the incorrect `'value'` when using the `'='` compare operator, and an unnecessary `'relation'` parameter.

```php
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    // array( <- an extra array you don't need
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'dummy',
                'value' => [false, null], // <- When using the '=' compare operator, the value cannot be an array, use an 'IN' compare value instead to see if the value of 'dummy' is 'IN' this array
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'merk',
                'value' => $machine['machine_merk'][0],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'merk_type',
                'value' => $machine['machine_type'][0],
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
        // array( <-------------------|
            // 'relation' => 'AND', <-| Unnecessary as there is only one array being compared here
            array(
                'key' => 'dummy',
                'value' => true,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        //)
    //)
);
```

So it should look like this:

```php
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'dummy',
            'value' => [false, null],
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'merk',
            'value' => $machine['machine_merk'][0],
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'merk_type',
            'value' => $machine['machine_type'][0],
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'dummy',
        'value' => true,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
);
```

Source: [WP_Meta_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)

Comment: Yes I saw the extra array later and removed it. The array over (dummy = true) is going to get multiple conditions but wanted this to work first. All and all this is cleaner code but it is still not working... Can't figure out why.

Comment: @MartvanderKruis I think you gotta specify then what your problem is. What is the expected result when you run your code? What is the actual result when you run your code? Please edit your original question to include more information that might be helpful.

Comment: Added some more info. So I need to get 39 results. The user input is definitely right .

Answer (score 0):

So when trying around I haven't gotten any further but maybe this is an even better example. This keeps returning NULL. On top of it all I need to clear all server cache every time because it stores the query even when i'm logged in and shouldn't do that.

```
$args['post_type'] = 'product';
$args['posts_per_page'] = 50;

//FROM CATEGORY
$args['tax_query'][] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $params['category'],
    'operator' => 'IN'
);

//BUILD ARGS
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            array(
                'key' => 'merk',
                'value' => 'CAT',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            //if I comment following array it works
            array(
                'key' => 'merk_type',
                'value' => '300.9D',
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        ),
        array(
            //or if I comment following array it also works
            array(
                'key' => 'merk',
                'value' => 'KUBOTA',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            //and something else
        )
    ),
    //maybe something else
);
```